# HTML 2 Select boxes always affects first one

Tags: html, css, forms, select, flexbox

I have been trying to create a form on my website, and would like to put 2 select boxes right next to each other. 
I managed to achieve this in 2 ways, first with flexbox and now I attempted to do it with table and table-cell to see if it would make any difference.

I got both to work on my PC just fine, but when checking it out on my mobile phone I discovered that whichever select box I use, it will always edit the value of the first box (this only happens on my phone and not on my PC which is what I don't understand)

My code:

```
<label>Km-stand
<div style="display:table">
<div style="display:table-cell">
  <select name="km-van" >
  <option value="">Van</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="5000">5.000</option>
  <option value="10000">10.000</option>
  <option value="20000">20.000</option>
  <option value="40000">40.000</option>
  <option value="60000">60.000</option>
  <option value="80000">80.000</option>
  <option value="100000">100.000</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="display:table-cell">
  <select name="km-tm" >
  <option value="">T/m</option>
  <option value="5000">5.000</option>
  <option value="10000">10.000</option>
  <option value="20000">20.000</option>
  <option value="40000">40.000</option>
  <option value="60000">60.000</option>
  <option value="80000">80.000</option>
  <option value="100000">100.000</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
</label>
```

Here is also a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p0qh6zbf/2/

EDIT: A quick follow up question, which would be better to use a flexbox or table for this?

Comment: What browser do you use in your phone? And could you try to see if that happens in another one too?

Comment: I have an iPhone, so safari, which iOS might also be a bit outdated
I just used another phone with android that did not have the issue.

Comment: Then it's probably a problem of the browser, because I don't see why would such a simple thing create such a problem.

Comment: To your second question, I don't think it's necessary to use something like a table or a flexbox for that, it's too simple.

Comment: How would you do it? Also I found the issue! Just posted answer

Comment: Great! I was also going to tell you about the label tag, but I had to get out of work ahhah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue, although it only happened in mobile Safari, what fixed it for me was closing the label immediently, and not after the select.
Like so:

```
<label>Km-stand</label>
<div style="display:table">
<div style="display:table-cell">
  <select name="km-van" >
  <option value="">Van</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="5000">5.000</option>
  <option value="10000">10.000</option>
  <option value="20000">20.000</option>
  <option value="40000">40.000</option>
  <option value="60000">60.000</option>
  <option value="80000">80.000</option>
  <option value="100000">100.000</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="display:table-cell">
  <select name="km-tm" >
  <option value="">T/m</option>
  <option value="5000">5.000</option>
  <option value="10000">10.000</option>
  <option value="20000">20.000</option>
  <option value="40000">40.000</option>
  <option value="60000">60.000</option>
  <option value="80000">80.000</option>
  <option value="100000">100.000</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A `label` may neither contain a `div` nor multiple controls (`input`, `select`, etc.). You should always validate your HTML: https://validator.w3.org/